# Understanding react-native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v6

I am wondering if react removes the components from its memory when you click `goback` or `navigation.pop()`

I am using `navigation.Push` and not `navigation.navigate` in this case.

Will there be any problems in memory and performance ?

Do I have to do somthing special to clear those ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [react-native-navigation lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle) a screen will remain mounted if you navigate away from a screen that you pushed on the `Stack`.

> Consider a native stack navigator with screens A and B. After navigating to A, its componentDidMount is called. When pushing B, its componentDidMount is also called, but A remains mounted on the stack and its componentWillUnmount is therefore not called.

On the other hand.

> When going back from B to A, componentWillUnmount of B is called, but componentDidMount of A is not because A remained mounted the whole time.

We can test this by creating a simple `StackNavigator` with two screens as in the documentation. Create a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array and log something as follows.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to ScreenA"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenA')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ScreenA({ navigation, route }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Screen A")
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to ScreenB"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenB')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ScreenB({ navigation, route }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Screen B")
  },[])

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to ScreenA"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenA')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ScreenA" component={ScreenA} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ScreenB" component={ScreenB} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Consider the following navigation route:

- `ScreenA` -> `ScreenB` -> `ScreenA` -> `ScreenB`

We will notice the following log messages:

- `ScreenA`, `ScreenB`, `ScreenB`

This is because **ScreenA remains mounted** while **ScreenB is unmounted and mounted again**.

Now, what happens if we `push` a screen? We can test this as well by using the same example but `pushing ScreenB in ScreenB itself` as follows.

```js
function ScreenB({ navigation, route }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Screen B")
  },[])

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Push to ScreenB"
        onPress={() => navigation.push('ScreenB')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

We will notice that on each `push` a new `ScreenB` is mounted!

What happens if we use `navigation.pop`? The screen that is being `poped` will be unmounted and the same will happen if we use `goBack` for the same reasons as provided above.

Performance-wise, using `navigation.pop()` or `navigation.goBack()` will release the memory of the screen in which we are calling these functions as they are unmounted.

On the other hand, constantly `pushing the same screen` on the `Stack` is not a good idea.

I would also consider on what code is located in `useEffect`. If it is an API call, then we often want it to be only called once. From that perspective it is desired that a screen remains mounted once we have entered it.

To summarize, `goBack` and `pop` will unmount the screen on which we are calling these functions. React native will release the memory occupied by the screen (in form of states, variables, etc.). You do not have to do anything special.

I have made a [little snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/navigation-lifecycle) using mainly the above code.